# Why are all the radio buttons already preselected when I run the code? I tried deselect but its not working. Please

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, radio-button

Why are all the radio buttons already preselected when I run the code? I tried deselect but its not working. Also the first radiobutton is not selected but when i hover my mouse over it, it gets selected. 
Please help. Updated the code and given more modules for reference. I want the radiobuttons to be selected and when submit is hit I want to know whether the answer is correct or not. But when I use self.var.get() I always get 0 as its value, which is denying me from helping my check my answer.

```
class Question:
    def __init__(self, question, answers, correctLetter):
        self.question = question
        self.answers = answers
        self.correctLetter = correctLetter



    def check(self, letter, view):
        print(self.var2.get())
        global right
        if(letter == self.correctLetter):
            label = Label(view, text="RIGHT!",bg='black',fg='green',font=("Calibri 11 bold"))
            right += 1
        else:
            label = Label(view, text="WRONG!",bg='black',fg='red',font=("Calibri 11 bold"))
##        label.pack()
        label.grid(row=10, column=2)
        view.after(1000, lambda *args: self.unpackView(view))


    def getView(self, window):

        view = Frame(window)

        self.var=IntVar()
        self.var1=IntVar()
        self.var2=IntVar()
        self.var3=IntVar()



        Label(view, text="Question: ").grid(sticky = W)
        Label(view, text=self.question).grid(sticky = E)


        r1=Checkbutton(view,text=self.answers[0],variable=self.var,onvalue = 1, offvalue = 0,command=lambda *args: self.check("A", view))
        r1.grid(sticky=W)

        Label(screen,text="").pack()


        r2=Checkbutton(view,text=self.answers[1],variable=self.var1,onvalue = 1, offvalue = 0,command=lambda *args: self.check("B", view))
        r2.grid(sticky=W)

        Label(screen,text="").pack()

        r3=Checkbutton(view,text=self.answers[2],variable=self.var2,onvalue = 1, offvalue = 0,command=lambda *args: self.check("C", view))
        r3.grid(sticky=W)

        Label(screen,text="").pack()

        r4=Checkbutton(view,text=self.answers[3],variable=self.var3,onvalue = 1, offvalue = 0,command=lambda *args: self.check("D", view))
        r4.grid(sticky=W)

        Label(screen,text="").pack()



        #tk.Radiobutton(view,text=self.answers[0],bg='white',font=('calibri',11),command=lambda *args: self.check("A", view),height=1,width=10).grid(row=5, column=2)
        #tk.Radiobutton(view,text=self.answers[0],bg='white',font=('calibri',11),command=lambda *args: self.check("B", view),height=1,width=10).grid(row=6, column=2)
        #tk.Radiobutton(view,text=self.answers[2],bg='white',font=('calibri',11),command=lambda *args: self.check("C", view),height=1,width=10).grid(row=7, column=2)
        #tk.Radiobutton(view,text=self.answers[3],bg='white',font=('calibri',11),command=lambda *args: self.check("D", view),height=1,width=10).grid(row=8, column=2)
        #Button(view,text='SUBMIT',fg='black',bg='white',font=('calibri',11),command=lambda *args: self.check(view),height=1,width=10).grid(sticky=SE)
        return view

    def unpackView(self, view):

        view.pack_forget()
        askQuestion()


def askQuestion():

    global questions, window, index, button, right, number_of_questions

    if(len(questions) == index + 1):
        Label(window, text="Thank you for answering the questions. " + str(right) + " of " + str(number_of_questions) + " questions answered right").place(x=40,y=400)
        return
    button.pack_forget()
    index += 1
    questions[index].getView(window).pack(padx=100,pady=100)
```

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Your current code works if i reduce it to just the bare bones so most likely something else is causing the issue you mentioned.

Comment: I have edited the code. Please suggest some edits.

Answer (score 0):

You need to initialize the IntVar with a value that is the one you want selected by default or a value that is not an option if you don't want any selected by default.

```
self.var=IntVar(value=1) # select the first Radiobutton on boot
self.var=IntVar(value=99) # no Radiobutton is selected on boot
```

Answer (score 0):

All radiobuttons in a group need to share a single instance of a tkinter variable (`StringVar`, `IntVar`, etc). Each radiobutton also needs a unique value. When you do that, and set the variable to one of the values, only the radiobutton with that value will be selected.

In your code, you weren't giving any radiobuttons a value so the default value of 0 (zero) was being set. Since they all had the same value, they all were set.

Example:

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()

var = tk.IntVar(value=0)
r0 = tk.Radiobutton(root, text="Zero", value=0, variable=var)
r1 = tk.Radiobutton(root, text="One", value=1, variable=var)
r2 = tk.Radiobutton(root, text="Two", value=2, variable=var)
r3 = tk.Radiobutton(root, text="Three", value=3, variable=var)

r0.pack(side="top", anchor="w")
r1.pack(side="top", anchor="w")
r2.pack(side="top", anchor="w")
r3.pack(side="top", anchor="w")

tk.mainloop()
```